# Question about tensor form of Maxwell equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, tensor-calculus, maxwell-equations

By variating the Maxwell Lagrangian we get the equation of motion. The remaining two Maxwell equations can be written as
$$\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial^{\rho} F^{\mu\nu} = 0.$$
I have also seen it written as the Bianchi identity: $$\partial_{[\lambda}F_{\mu\nu]} = 0.$$
Why are these two forms equivalent?

Comment: Please see edit. It's important to use understandable punctuation etc. so that others can understand the question.

Comment: Have you tried plugging in the components of $F_{\mu \nu}$? Both forms are equivalent to the same two Maxwell equations, thus they are obviously mutually equivalent.

Comment: VTC due to insufficient  research,  sorry.

Comment: I know they are equivalent by plugging the components of $F_{\mu\nu}$, But can we prove it  by pure mathematicas only with $F_{\mu\nu}$ is antisymmetric.

Comment: In both expressions everything is explicitly antisymmetrized, so I think you don't need antisymmetry of F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically just a [duality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual) relation analogous to the cross product in three dimensions. But if you want to do some work to *show* the equivalence, then:

Going from the second equation to the first is easy, just hit it with $\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$.

Going from the first to the second equation, is a little trickier and relies on knowing how to evaluate the products of [Levi-Civita symbols](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol).
The basic idea is that you should contact the first equation with $\epsilon^{\mu'\nu'\lambda'\sigma}$ and compare the resulting antisymmetric combination of $\delta$s with the antisymmetrization of the indices in the second equation.